# Symfony: Error when overriding third party Service

Tags: symfony, service, parameters, arguments, overriding

I'm using a third party bundle for notifications in my application. It's all working fine, however I'd like to override some parts of the Service "NotificationManager" of that Bundle in order to combine notifications with emails.

**Error**
After everything was implemented, I got the following error message:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Mgilet\NotificationBundle\Twig\NotificationExtension::__construct() must be an instance of Mgilet\NotificationBundle\Manager\NotificationManager, instance of NewsBundle\Services\NotificationHelper given, called in /srv/http/sp/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 4011
```

**What I did**
I followed the Symfony documentation and added a CompilerPass:

```
    <?php
namespace NewsBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use NewsBundle\Services\NotificationHelper;

class OverrideCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface {

  public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
      {
          $defNewService = $container->getDefinition('mgilet.notification');
          $defNewService->setClass('NewsBundle\Services\NotificationHelper');

      }

}
  ?>
```

and also marked my custom bundle as an inheritance of the NotificationBundle:

```
    <?php

namespace NewsBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Mgilet\NotificationBundle\MgiletNotificationBundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use NewsBundle\DependencyInjection\OverrideCompilerPass;

class NewsBundle extends MgiletNotificationBundle
{
  public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
   {
       parent::build($container);
       $container->addCompilerPass(new OverrideCompilerPass());
   }
}
```

I then basically copied and pasted the Service Class from the third party bundle, just to double check that everything is still working fine.

```
 <?php
namespace NewsBundle\Services;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Mgilet\NotificationBundle\Model\AbstractNotification;
use Mgilet\NotificationBundle\Model\UserNotificationInterface;

class NotificationHelper{
      private $om;
      private $notification;
      private $repository;

      /**
       * NotificationHelper constructor.
       * @param EntityManager $om
       * @param $notification
       * @internal param $class
       */
      public function __construct(EntityManager $om, $notification)
      {
          $this->om = $om;
          $this->notification = $notification;
          $this->repository = $om->getRepository($notification);
      }
... all the functions from the bundle

}
```

Now I also need a Twig Extension to make everything work and here my error appears:

```
<?php

namespace NewsBundle\Twig;

use Mgilet\NotificationBundle\Twig\NotificationExtension as BaseExtension;
use NewsBundle\Services\NotificationHelper;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;
use Twig_Extension;

class NotificationExtension extends BaseExtension
/**
 * Twig extension to display notifications
 **/
{
    protected $notificationHelper;
    protected $storage;
    protected $twig;

    /**
     * NotificationExtension constructor.
     * @param NotificationHelper $notificationHelper
     * @param TokenStorage $storage
     * @param \Twig_Environment $twig
     */
    public function __construct(NotificationHelper $notificationHelper, TokenStorage $storage, \Twig_Environment $twig)
    {
        $this->notificationHelper = $notificationHelper;
        $this->storage = $storage;
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }
... stuff happening
}
```

I thought that by replacing the first parameter of the construct function and the use statement would automatically override the third party bundle but it seems like it's not really working.

In my config.yml file I have:

```
     notification_helper:
      class: NewsBundle\Services\NotificationHelper
      arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', AppBundle\Entity\Notification]

  notification.twig_extension:
          class: NewsBundle\Twig\NotificationExtension
          arguments: ['@notification_helper', '@security.token_storage', '@twig']
          public: false
          tags:
              - { name: twig.extension }
```

**update**

I edited the services.yml, so that now only the twig_extension is left as a service, because when I debugged the mgilet.notification-service it was already assigned to my custom Service class, so I thought that it is just the same..

so now I only have this in my file:

```
    notification.twig_extension:
      class: NewsBundle\Twig\NotificationExtension
      arguments: ['@mgilet.notification', '@security.token_storage', '@twig']
      public: false
      tags:
          - { name: twig.extension }
```

when debugging the container, it doesn't even show up as a service but the error message stays the same:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Mgilet\NotificationBundle\Twig\NotificationExtension::__construct() must be an instance of Mgilet\NotificationBundle\Manager\NotificationManager, instance of NewsBundle\Services\NotificationHelper given, called in /srv/http/sp/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 4000
```

Comment: did you clear all cache?

Comment: yes, but when clearing the cache I get the same error..
     [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]                                                    
  Type error: Argument 1 passed to Mgilet\NotificationBundle\Twig\NotificationExtension::__construct() must  
   be an instance of Mgilet\NotificationBundle\Manager\NotificationManager, instance of NewsBundle\Services  
  \NotificationHelper given, called in /srv/http/sp/app/cache/de_/appDevDebugProjectContaine_.php on line 3  
  998

Comment: did you clear the cache after you updated your service arguments?

Comment: yes I did, but the error remained.. :)

Comment: @sonja did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @NicholasBetsworth unfortunately I have no insight into the code anymore so I can'T check how I eventually solved the situation.. sorry for being no help!

Answer (score 0):

I think NotificationExtension need to NotificationManager class. You should send this class from services.yml. But you're sending your service class; NotificationHelper. You should send add one and it is Notification Manager class. So NotificationHelper is in NotificationBundle.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't quite understand what you tried to say :/
if you mean, that I try to send the wrong parameter, I already changed that one  (see my updated question)
But it's still the same error..

Comment: You did send NotificationHelper class but you should send NotificationManager class from services.yml.

Comment: yes that's waht I meant, I edited it
but do you mean that I should also call the NotificationManager in the construct function?